# Why does JQuery write [object Object] to the DOM when I try to append an element?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Simplified, this is what I have:

```
if (value instanceof jQuery && target instanceof jQuery) {
   target.append(value);
}
```

And it's appending this:

```
[object Object]
```

I've also tried converting the value to html:

```
if (value instanceof jQuery && target instanceof jQuery) {
   target.append(value.html());
}
```

Same result.

I've also tried setting the target's html, rather than appending the elem:

```
if (value instanceof jQuery && target instanceof jQuery) {
   target.html(value.html());
}
```

Same result.

Can anyone point me in the right direction?

`value` is this, when inspected in the debugger:

```
Z.fn.init[1]

0: span.jc-template-formatted-currency
context: span.jc-template-formatted-currency
length: 1
prevObject: Z.fn.init[1]
__proto__: Z[0]
```

`target` is created by another large class that I won't include here, but here's the basics:

```
$(document.getElementById('protos').querySelector('.jc-template-formatted-currency')).clone().find(targetSelector);
```

(protos is a template store in the DOM).

So `target` is not actually in the DOM at the time of appending `value`. `target` is first pushed to an array and appended to a container (`$('.container)`) with various other elements later)

Comment: Can you add a snippet?

Comment: What's contained in the `value`? Please add more code.

Comment: What are the contents of your jQuery object in `value`?  Does it have DOM elements in it?  Or regular Javascript objects?

Comment: Nope, jQuery doesn't append `[Object object]` unless you somehow do `value.toString()` somewhere

Comment: Can you make a small working code sample that shows this behavior?

Comment: I added some debugging info about `value` -- I'll work on getting this up on plunkr in the meantime.

Comment: There's something hinky there, it should be `jQuery.fn.init` not `z.fn.init`, and generally context is the `document`, so you're doing something strange that you're not showing us.

Comment: Try `value[0]`? eg: `target.append(value[0])`

Comment: How does value and target get their values??

Comment: Try $(value).el or similar. I'd need to know more about "value", but value.el or $(value.el) maybe?

Comment: In short, target == $(elem).find(selector) and value == $(otherelem) with some text (`text()`) added to elements inside it.

Comment: So weird you are mixing querySelector with jQuery....

Comment: Yeah, I didn't write the library. I think they wanted to minimize use of jquery where possible.

Comment: Can you [edit] your question to include a [mcve]? Otherwise this question is off-topic as per the [help/on-topic]